# Importing modules Python

Tags: python, module, python-import

Hey I am having some trouble figuring out what is being asked to import in this code

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python

import sys
from formatter import Formatter

def main():
#do stuff
```

in my class formatter.py, do I have had to define a function with a name Formatter.  A little confused on this.  I have been testing my code by putting

```
from formatter import *
```

Which takes all the definitions in my class(I believe).

Comment: `formatter.py` is a module, not a class, and by convention, `Formatter` would be a class, not a function. But yes, you’d create something with that name.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import The docs are a great place to start. You should always Google before going to SO.

Answer (score 0):

your line `from formatter import Formatter` will search through the module formatter for anything with the name `Formatter`. 
so if you had a function called `Formatter` in that module, it would be imported, meaning you could use it in your main section (anywhere below the import line will work)
It will import classes as well.

`formatter.py` is a module. a class might look something like:

```
class A:
    variable = 1
    def b():
        #do stuff
```